# Problem with the point transformation of the Lagrangian

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, time

Page no 36 ie. the 2nd page of the PDF: https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~shapiro/507/book3.pdf

there is a line at the bottom which states that the lagrangian is a function of $q$ and $\dot q$ and goes on with the partial derivative. Why does it not account for the time $t$ since $L(q,\dot q, t)$ is generally the form of a lagrangian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In context, it means that we can replace $(x,\dot x)$ with $(q, \dot q)$.  It does not mean that the Lagrangian is not explicitly a function of time.

More explicitly, it could have read

> We may consider $L$ as a function of the generalized coordinates $q_j$ and $\dot q_j$ *rather than the Cartesian coordinates $x_i$ and $\dot x_i$*, and ask [...]

Comment: they are taking a partial wrt $\dot x$ just after that. should not they include the $(dL/dt)(dt/d \dot x)$ term too? (the expression I typed should be in partial though )

Comment: Is $t$ a function of $\dot x$?

Comment: but we can invert it right?

Comment: No.  This is one of those cases where it's very dangerous to imagine that derivatives are just fractions.  You need to look very carefully at how the chain rule works.

Comment: @Icchyamoy To put it in casual terms, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}$ is the derivative of $L$ while holding $x$ and $t$ constant.  Such a derivative would generally correspond to changing $q$ and $\dot q$ (which are themselves functions of $\dot x$), but not to changing $t$, which we explicitly keep constant.